# How to resolve 400 Bad Request error in Postman in a sample MEAN application

Tags: postman, mean

I am working on a sample MEAN application where in I have started to create the node.js related files and connected the same to MongoDB. I have create a POST call which sends the json to the DB. I tried to test the api using postman but not sure whats wrong, I have checked multiple times, the api throws bad request.Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Added the relevant route.js, app.js and contact.js files for reference in stackblitz link. Added error in postman for reference.

[image: postman]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-mlodls?file=app.js

[image]

Comment: It is `http://localhost:3000`, not `localhost:3000`, you're missing protocol part.

Comment: I have tried with http as well, still getting same error 400 Bad request. Attached screen shot for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue using postman extension. Wondering why the API doesnt work in postman software and works in postman extension

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? I faced a similar problem and my code works with "postman extension" on chrome.

Comment: Exactly.. I forgot to post my answer, i tried postman extension and it worked perfectly fine, but not in postman

Comment: Yes, it is very weird that the Postman desktop client being one of the best tools has such a strange problem. I have posted our problem here: https://community.postman.com/t/how-to-resolve-400-bad-request-errors-on-post-request-for-a-sample-mern-application/32409/4 
If you find an answer keep me updated, please. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enable Content-Length and Host headers. Then it works.
The purpose of the HTTP Host header is to help identify which back-end component the client wants to communicate with.
Refer: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8768